# Python generated dynamic schema for all db tables

Tags: python, sql-server

I want generated test data for multiple tables using a python script.

Can you please help me if any module is there to generate schema for db tables dynamically without defining columns.

So that we can generate test data for multiple tables.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. What do you mean by "generate schema"? I don't think you mean a database schema but can't figure out what you want to accomplish.

Comment: If you are just looking for a tool to generate test data there are literally hundreds if not thousands of tools that can do that in nearly every database for every language.

Comment: We have a task, that we need to completed this with using python only. Is there any tool that supports python. Can you help me on this.

Comment: The basic task is , fetching meta data(columns and datatypes ) from database tables and create a csv file with those columns and generete faker data . for this we need to define a method like generateSchema(fields,datatypes) . The method contain the logic of convertion of datatypes from db to python datatypes and generate faker data for that table . But I am not able to write a logic with out defining columns.

Comment: Tool or other resource recommendations are off-topic.